# How to remove border that shows after click in b-form-checkbox in BootstrapVue

Tags: css, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to remove border after clicking in option in select box.
Here the vue part:

```
<b-form-checkbox-group v-model="selected">
  <b-form-checkbox v-for= "element in options" :key="element.text">
    <div>{{element.text}}</div>
  </b-form-checkbox>
</b-form-checkbox-group>
```

and data:

```
        selected: null,
        options: [{
            value: null,
            text: 'Please select an option'
          },
          {
            value: 'a',
            text: 'This is First option'
          },
          {
            value: 'b',
            text: 'Selected Option'
          },
          {
            value: {
              C: '3PO'
            },
            text: 'This is an option with object value'
          },
          {
            value: 'd',
            text: 'This one is disabled',
            disabled: true
          }
        ]
      }
```

I had the similar issue but solved it removing box-shadow. It this case I tried:

```
.custom-control-input, .custom-control-input::before, .custom-control-input:focus {
  border: 0 !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  outline: none !important;
}
```

but nothing change. How can I remove border that shows after click?

Comment: Depending on your target audience, avoid fully hiding it, it's horrible to try navigating through an web-app without highlightying by using tab + enter.

I don't know vue bootstrap, but the .custom-control-input is the actual input?

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I didn't know about it but got this task in work. So I'll discuss about it. Yes, .custom-control-input is the class with actual input.

Comment: Have you tried outline: 0; ?

Comment: Yes and it doesn't work

Comment: Custom styled checkboxes are styled by Bootstrap v4.4 SCSS/CSS as `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements, as well as the `:focus` selector.  Clicking an element typically also gives it focus.  If you expect your website to be accessible (required by law in many jurisdictions) don't hide focus rings.  But if you have to, see: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_custom-forms.scss

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.custom-control:focus {
    outline: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about?

```
input.custom-control-input:focus {

    outline:none !important;
    outline-width: 0 !important;
    box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}
```